# .NET Framework 4.8 UserSecretsConfigBuilder "Expand" (v2.0) and "Token" (v3.0) modes don't replace all tokens

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, system.configuration

I am using Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecretsConfigBuilder and trying to update tokens in my web.config file. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/config-builder) mentions that `mode="Expand"` (update: and now `mode="Token"` in v3.0) in the builders config should operate on raw XML of web.config file and replace any tokens it finds with pattern `${...}`; however this is not the case in my experience.

Here is my config section:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />      
</configSections>
<configBuilders>
    <builders>
        <add name="Secrets" userSecretsFile="~\secrets.xml" mode="Expand" optional="true" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecretsConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecrets, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </builders>
</configBuilders>
```

However, down below, I have a token for my content security policy that is not getting replaced when I run the app:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="${ContentSecurityPolicy}" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Likewise, this is replacing the tokens neither in my `system.serviceModel` nor `system.net` sections.

Is the documentation simply wrong, and it still only operates on `appSettings` and `connectionStrings`?  That would be a huge bummer.